# how to get zend subform values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, subform

I have zend project up and running. How to get zend subform values and save it in a controller?

If I use `extends Zend_Form` it's working. But if I use `extends Zend_Form_SubForm` it's not showing the form values.

I use the following code in my controller to show the values:

```
public function registerAction() {

         $baseForm = new BaseForm();
         $this->view->baseForm = $baseForm;

         $request=$this->getRequest();

          if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
              $baseForm = new BaseForm();
              if ($baseForm->isValid( $request->getPost()) ) {
                  $baseData = array(
                      'id'=>$baseForm->getValue('id'),
                     'name'=>$baseForm->getValue('username'),
                  );
                   print_r($baseData);
                         exit;
              }
          }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am using zend framework 1.12.